# Count nodes in prolog

Tags: prolog

I tried to count all the nodes in the tree but there is a mistake in some where

```
Count_tree(tree(_,Left,Right),Count):- 
   Count_tree(Left,S1),Count_tree(Right,S2),Count is 1+S1+S2.
```

This is my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predicate names must be atoms, so:

```
count_tree(tree(_,Left,Right),Count):- 
    count_tree(Left,S1),
    count_tree(Right,S2),
    Count is 1+S1+S2.
```

But this is a recursive rule. What happens when you reach a tree leaf node? Where's your base case?